# HTML Input type text not allow number

Tags: javascript, validation, jsp

I have a input type text, in jsp page 
How can i set event onchange in javascript, not allow number, just allow character, and Vietnamese. 
Thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function lettersOnly(input) {
    var regex = /[^a-z ]/gi;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)">
```

This strips out numbers from the input. However, I am not sure it will work for Vietnamese! P.S. It also strips out the special characters.

Here's one that will basically strips out only numbers:

```js
function lettersOnly(input) {
    var regex = /[0-9]/g;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)">
```

Comment: I try this : 
      var input = document.getElementById("your-full-name");
 input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
But it not allow i type vietnamese :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sanjay's answer, and what this Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_language_and_computers) says about the Unicode encoding of Vietnamese, I came up with the following:

```js
function vietnameseNoNumbers(input) {
    var regex = /[^-a-z !@&*():;"',./\u0080-\u024F\u0300-\u036F\u1E00-\u1Eff\u1DC4]/ig;
    input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="vietnameseNoNumbers(this)" size="50">
```

I added spaces and some basic punctuation to what is allowed -- you can modify the regex as needed for what you want to allow or not.